# When I build a project in flutter it is asking me about update to java 11 , i have jdk 14 istalled , how to fix it in vs code

Tags: java, android, flutter, java-11

> You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle.
>
> To get Java 11, update to the latest version of Android Studio on https://developer.android.com/studio/install.
>
> To check the Java version used by Flutter, run `flutter doctor -v`.

Comment: Ok, So what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio in Settings->Build,Execution Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle change to Java 1.8

Comment: how to change it in vs code , even gradle always downloading how to fix it

Comment: I don't know sorry